# How to use Spring Data JPA in a simple Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-data-jpa

I'm very new to Spring, but I am working on a project which is using Spring Data JPA to generate repositories for JPA entities.

I'm currently adding a simple module to be able to show some data on a webpage. I have added a Servlet, but I am having trouble accessing the repositories from there.

I have added a ContextLoaderListener in web.xml, I'm referencing the jpa:repositories and persistence.xml in the applicationContext.xml, but I'm currently stuck with this exception:

> No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0.

But when I add an EntityManagerFactory in persistence.xml I get the following cryptic message:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyle.STYLES from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.EJB3CascadeStyle

My question is: is what I am trying to do even possible? And if so, how?
Or should I just bite the bullet and use Spring MVC or something else entirely?

Note: this is just for a one-page web site and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Spring Data JPA you need to configure the underlying JPA implementation as you would typically do in Spring, see for example, `infrastructure.xml` and `META-INF/persistence.xml` in [`spring-data-jpa-showcase`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples/tree/master/spring-data-jpa-showcase/src/main/resources) (since Spring 3.1 you can get rid of `persistence.xml` if you use `packagesToScan` property of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`).

Your second problem with `IllegalAccessError` looks like a classloading problem caused by presence of different versions of Hibernate jars in classpath.